# How do I change my google profile picture

Tags: google-docs

Every time I try to change my google profile picture. it says an embedded google docs page can't save it. I want to change my picture how do I? without it doing that?

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details including the steps you are following and a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To change your google profile picture click the + button on the top of your computer then click the first letter of your first name on the top right corner. then click on the tiny camera. next click on select photo then select your photo